# Why does Angular 5 component refresh quicker with an explicit focus?

Tags: angular, web-component

I have written a custom component that uses Google Places Autocomplete (code below). For those not familiar, when a user types in an input box, this shows an autocomplete they can use to pick a qualified address.  The component works fine, but when it emits the picked address, it takes several seconds before the new value is bound in the parent.  If I focus() the input box at the same time the address is emitted (see last line in code below), the new value is bound immediately.  Why is this and is there a better way to ensure the new value gets bound immediately?

To be clear, I don't think this issue is with Places autocomplete per se, just some Angular internal I don't understand.

On parent page:

```
<google-address-picker [(value)]="foo"></google-address-picker>
{{foo.fullAdress}} //Without focus() line below, this takes several seconds to populate.
```

Component code:

```
import { Component, ElementRef, Input, Output, EventEmitter, ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'google-address-picker',
  templateUrl: 'google-address-picker.html'
})
export class GoogleAddressPickerComponent {

   autocomplete: any;
   googleAddressComponents: any = {};
   googlePlace: any = {};
   address: any = {};
   @Output() valueChange: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();
   @Input() value: any = { fullAddress: '' };

   constructor(private elRef: ElementRef) {
   }

   ngAfterViewInit() {
      var self = this;
      var addressElement = 
      this.elRef.nativeElement.querySelector('.addressElement');
      var anyWindow: any = window;
      var google: any = anyWindow.google;
      this.autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(addressElement, {});
      self.autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', () => this.changed());
      addressElement.addEventListener('blur', function () {
         self.valueChange.emit(self.value);
       });
   }

    changed() {  
       var self = this;
       self.googlePlace = self.autocomplete.getPlace();  
       self.googleAddressComponents = {};
       self.address = { latitude: null, longitude: null, street: '', city: '', stateName: '', stateCode: '', zipCode: '', countryName: '', countryCode: '', fullAddress: '' };
       if (self.googlePlace && self.googlePlace.address_components) {
         for (var i = 0; i < self.googlePlace.address_components.length; i++) {
           var component = self.googlePlace.address_components[i];
           self.googleAddressComponents[component.types[0]] = component.long_name;
           if (component.short_name)
              self.googleAddressComponents[component.types[0] + '_code'] = component.short_name;
          }
         }
         if (self.googleAddressComponents.administrative_area_level_1) self.address.stateName = self.googleAddressComponents.administrative_area_level_1;
         if (self.googleAddressComponents.administrative_area_level_1_code && self.googleAddressComponents.administrative_area_level_1_code.length === 2) self.address.stateCode = self.googleAddressComponents.administrative_area_level_1_code;
         if (self.googleAddressComponents.country) self.address.countryName = self.googleAddressComponents.country;
         if (self.googleAddressComponents.country_code) self.address.countryCode = self.googleAddressComponents.country_code;
         if (self.googleAddressComponents.locality) self.address.city = self.googleAddressComponents.locality;
         if (self.googleAddressComponents.route) self.address.street = self.googleAddressComponents.route;
         if (self.googleAddressComponents.street_number) self.address.street = [self.googleAddressComponents.street_number, self.address.street].join(' ');
         if (self.googleAddressComponents.postal_code) self.address.zipCode = self.googleAddressComponents.postal_code;

         if (self.googlePlace && self.googlePlace.formatted_address)
  self.address.fullAddress = self.googlePlace.formatted_address;
         if (self.googlePlace && self.googlePlace.geometry && self.googlePlace.geometry.location) {
             self.address.latitude = self.googlePlace.geometry.location.lat();
             self.address.longitude = self.googlePlace.geometry.location.lng();
         }
         if (!self.value) self.value = {};    
         for (var key in self.address)
            self.value[key] = self.address[key];
         self.valueChange.emit(self.value);
         var addressElement = this.elRef.nativeElement.querySelector('.addressElement');
         addressElement.focus(); //Not sure why, but this triggers immediate Angular refresh.  Without, refresh can be several seconds.        
   };
  }
```

Comment: sounds like a change detection issue in the parent... have you tried this without using two way binding?

Comment: why are you emitting value on blur? I think It should emit when the place_changed.

Comment: @Akhilesh I emit on both.  See 3rd line from bottom in changed event handler.  I think you're right that blur is not really needed, but don't think that's causing the issue.